# CDATA removing new line in script tag in wordpress

Tags: javascript, tags

I am getting this error in 4.1.6 suddenly.
The code below when put in the editor

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
alert('hello');
//]]>
</script>
```

gets converted to

```
// <![CDATA[ alert('hello'); // ]]>
```

and the js code doesnt execute. I had an embedded twitter feed code in my site which has stopped working because of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is being caused by [core bug #33106](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33106) which was unfortunately introduced with the security fixes in 4.1.6 (and 4.2.3). New lines are erroneously being stripped from CDATA blocks in this situation.

From the bug ticket:

> As of 4.2.3, depending on how a CDATA block is used, the stripping of new lines in this content may break when displayed on the front end, even when published with unfiltered_html capabilities.

A fix is in the works and should be released in 4.1.7 (and 4.2.4). More info here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/30/wordpress-4-2-4-release-candidate-1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope it will auto update and I dont need to do anything.